# VS Code: Why the syntax coloring in Python script is different of the Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

As the title states, when I write a code in a Python script file (extension: `.py`), the code seems to be fully colored like this:
[image]

But when writing the same code in a Jupyter notebook (extension: `.ipynb`), the code seems to be partially colored like this:
[image]
Am I missing any configuration in the Python extension or is it a bug?

I am working on Windows and I have the extension pack from Microsoft for Pyhton and Jupyter:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The color theme is Dark+ (default dark).

Answer (score 0):

Python extension is used in your .py files. Instead, in .ipynb it works with Jupyter Extension.

Comment: Yes. But both extensions are by the same developer. I think the coloring should be the same. Or else, what is the reason for this difference?